# Update a column in database from the column by CheckBox in front end

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms, ado.net

**Hi Respected Sir/Ma'am,

There are four columns in an `Employee` table, EmpID, EmpName, Address, Status. I'd like to update the status column from front by CheckBox. In below given, code I'm experiencing **'Index-out of range'** exception. Please note that Emp_Status is type of integer in this case. However, if I update Emp_Status row by row in edit mode. In this case, checkbox is checked where Emp_Status having 1 value, and unchecked where is 0. My requirement is, if user check/uncheck either one checkbox or multiple across paging, then on this basis value shall be updated in database as well.

I am not a software developer, I am just a learner, never worked in IT so far, so just learning. Please help me out.
                                **

**Database table structure**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee](
    [Employee_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Employee_Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Employee_Address] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Emp_Status] [int] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Employee_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON
```

**Webform**

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Employee Name: </td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txt_EmployeeName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Employee Address: </td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txt_EmployeeAddress" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><asp:Button ID="btn_Submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btn_Submit_Click" style="width: 61px" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><asp:LinkButton ID="Link_Search" runat="server" Text="Go For Search"></asp:LinkButton></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Enter Name or Email ID for Search: </td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txt_Search" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><asp:Button ID="btn_Search" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="btn_Search_Click" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:GridView ID="GV_Product" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" GridLines="Vertical" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="true" OnRowEditing="GV_Product_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GV_Product_RowUpdating" OnRowDeleting="GV_Product_RowDeleting" OnRowCancelingEdit="GV_Product_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowCommand="GV_Product_RowCommand" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5" OnPageIndexChanging="GV_Product_PageIndexChanging">
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="Gainsboro" />

                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Employee ID">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_ID" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Employee_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Employee Name">
                              <ItemTemplate>
                                  <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Name" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Employee_Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                              </ItemTemplate>

                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEdit_Name" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Employee_Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>

                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAdd_Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <%--<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="txtName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAdd_Name" ErrorMessage="Please enter Employee Name"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>--%>
                                </FooterTemplate>

                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Employee Address">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Address" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Employee_Address") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </ItemTemplate>

                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEdit_Address" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Employee_Address") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>

                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAdd_Address" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" />
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?')" />

                                </ItemTemplate> 

                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update" />
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" />
                                </EditItemTemplate>

                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lblAdd" runat="server" Width="100px" Text="Add" CommandName="ADD"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkBox" runat="server" Checked='<%# GetStatus(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Emp_Status").ToString() )%>' AutoPostBack="true"
                                        Text='<%# Eval("Emp_Status").ToString()=="1"?"Active":"Inactive" %>' OnCheckedChanged="ChkBox_CheckedChanged"    
                                        />
                                </ItemTemplate>

                                <%--<EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="EditChkBox" runat="server" Checked='<%# GetStatus(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Emp_Status").ToString() )%>' Text='<%# Eval("Emp_Status").ToString()=="1"?"Active":"Inactive" %>'/>

                                </EditItemTemplate>--%>
                            </asp:TemplateField>


                        </Columns>
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#000084" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" ForeColor="Black" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#008A8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0000A9" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#000065" />
                    </asp:GridView>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Code behind**

```
 protected void ChkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox ChkBox = (CheckBox)sender;
        //int eID = -1;
        //eID = Convert.ToInt32(GV_Product.DataKeys[((GridViewRow)ChkBox.NamingContainer).RowIndex].Value);



        string sQuery = "UPDATE Employee SET Emp_Status = @Status WHERE Employee_ID = @ID";
        string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(consString))
        {
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sQuery, conn);

            com.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.Int).Value =0;
            com.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = eID;

            conn.Open();
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        BindGV();
    }


 protected void GV_Product_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GV_Product.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        BindGV();
    }

protected bool GetStatus(string str)
{
    if (str=="1")
    {
        return true;
    }

    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

     protected void BindGV()
    {
        string Table_Name = "Employee";
        BAL obj = new BAL();
        DataTable dt = obj.Select(Table_Name);

        GV_Product.DataSource = dt;      
        GV_Product.DataBind();
    }
```

**Data binding classes**

```
public class BAL
{
      public DataTable Select(string table)
        {
            string query = "Select *from " + table;

            DAL obj = new DAL();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = obj.Select(query);
            return dt;
        }
}

public class DAL
{
    public DataTable Select(string query)
    {
        SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(ConString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        cmd.Connection = Con;
        Con.Open();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        Con.Close();
        return dt;

    }
}
```

Comment: Plz help........

Comment: what is the class `BAL` ?

Comment: where is btn_Submit_Click  in your C# code?

Comment: I don't think there is any issue in BAL. Since, it edit mode, I can easily update one row, but I wanna make it more feasible so that user can change status of multiple employees.

Comment: in BindGV() the binding is done getting table from BAL

Comment: Yes.............

Comment: Please update question. Add `btn_Submit_Click()` and class `BAL`. When are you getting "Index-out of range"? Which code line? Is that in `ChkBox_CheckedChanged()` when you do `eID = Convert.ToInt32(GV_Product.DataKeys[((GridViewRow)ChkBox.NamingContainer).RowIndex].Value);` ?

Comment: Yes..Sir this error is coming from checkbox_checked event

Comment: Ignore btn submit in this case...this belongs to value from Text box outside grid view

Comment: Your code is incomplete. For that reason the function cannot be debugged.

Comment: It's updated in question, please see Sir!

Comment: Thanks a lot from bottom of my heart! Would you please elaborate more in a simple way as you have done now.  about first line "Naming Container'

Comment: in your GridView each row has a check box, in other words, the check box is contained into a row. `ChkBox.NamingContainer` is getting the row of the checkbox you clicked. Then RowIndex is the number of the row as they are displayed on the page (0,1,2,3,4,5...).

Comment: If this solves the issue please mark as solved.

Comment: I've deleted my answer but I understand you already have copy of the code.

Comment: Sir Sorry, I was seeing all this on my phone, although I am having that code now, but I would like to give you point as well, plz paste your solution, so that I can do that....plz don't mind it.